# Trigger a journey on addition of a new row in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey with Data Extension as its entry source. The journey contains an email right after the entry source. I get data into DE through an API call(to insert or update rows).

My requirement is to trigger that journey and send an email as soon as a new row is inserted in my DE. Because I have DE as my entry event, I don't get real time emails.

This problem is similar to this one: [Journey entry event using new contacts in Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186150/journey-entry-event-using-new-contacts-in-data-extension)

But I am unable to reproduce the solution.

Comment: Just as a note, the link is no longer valid, it'd be great if you provide more context around what was discussed in that link and the solution from that post that you've mentioned in your question, Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A - the question was deleted, but presented more ore less same outline as in this question above. And there is still no direct trigger on adding new rows to data extensions.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to trigger anything in real time based on entries being added to a Data Extension. 
I will instead recommend an approach where you utilise [API to trigger Journey Builder entry event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/get-started-jb.htm) - just as suggested in the post you refer too. What have you attempted when trying to recreate the solution suggested?

Brgds
Lukas